# Player movement script like in FPS, Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 scripts, which make player move like in the FPS game. But it don't move to that direction, to which player are looking - it always move to the same direction, regardless of the direction of the camera..

**mouselook.cs**

```
float yRotation;
float xRotation;
float lookSensitivity = 5;
float currentXRotation;
float currentYRotation;
float yRotationV;
float xRotationV;
float lookSmoothnes = 0.1f; 

void Update ()
{
    yRotation += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSensitivity;
    xRotation -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSensitivity;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -80, 100);
    currentXRotation = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentXRotation, xRotation, ref xRotationV, lookSmoothnes);
    currentYRotation = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentYRotation, yRotation, ref yRotationV, lookSmoothnes);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
}
```

**playermovement.cs**

```
public float walkSpeed = 6.0F;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
public float runSpeed = 8.0F;
public float gravity = 20.0F;

private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
private CharacterController controller;

void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= walkSpeed;
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
    }
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using lateUpdate() for playermovement.cs

Comment: @BurakKarasoy now I tried to use it instead `Update`, but it didn't helped

Comment: I would try to create a function in playermovement.cs function and carry all codes in update here then call this function end of mouselook.cs's update function to understand if issue is between these two script's synchronization.

Comment: Are both your scripts attached to the character GameObject? I tried reproduce your problem, but it works very well.

Comment: @ziwert it was the problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your mouse look like this

```
float lookSensitivity = 5;
float mouseX,mouseY;
public Transform playerBody;
float xRotation = 0f;

void Update ()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSentivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSentivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);

        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

}
```

save this and Drag your Player from hierarchy to the camera script playerBody.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it need like a requirecomponentTypeof or something like  that

Comment: Please be more clarified with your answers